# Click tab update filter pipe value Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-pipe

This time, I am getting data from an API but I would like to filter it. Here is the login.
People -> Filter by Status (Enable or disable)

I have the following files

- people.component.ts
- people.component.html
- people.pipe.ts

### JSON File

- {"Name": "Ana","Status": "Enable"},
- {"Name": "Marcelo","Status": "Enable"},
- {"Name": "Rod","Status": "Disable"}

### people.component.ts

```
export class peopleComponent implements OnInit {

    /* General Variables */
    titlePage: string = "People";
    errorMessage: string;
    filterPeople: string  = "Enable";

    people: iPeople[]; // Call the service, this is fine 

    constructor(private _peopleService: peopleListService){

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this._peopleService.getInfo()
        .subscribe(
            people => this.people = people,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

### people.pipe.ts

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'peopleTab'
})
export class peopleTabsPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: iPeopleList[], args: string[]): iPeopleList[] {
        let filter: string = args[0] ? args[0].toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        return filter ? value.filter((people: iPeopleList) => people.Status.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) : value;
    }
}
```

### people.component.html

```
<template ngFor #person [ngForOf]="people | peopleTab:filterPeople">
      <div class="Tabs">
            <ul>
               <li class="active" data-tab="1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Active</a></li>
               <li data-tab="2"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Past</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      <div class="information">{{person.Name}} {{person.Status}}</div>
</template>
```

---

By default is filtered by "Enable" but I can't transfer a var to the past tab to change the value of the filter

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for impure pipes.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'peopleTab',
    pure: false
})
```

Only impure pipes are run when elements of an array are changed.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: Thanks mate, but know how I created the click event to change the filter parameters?

Comment: <button (click)="onClick()">Toggle</button> then use onClick() in your component class to change the value of filterPeople